# React Native Navigator always goes back to first screen on screen rotation

Tags: android, react-native, react-router, navigator

New to react native

I have implemented navigator this way :

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    var routeId = route.id;
    console.log("myid: " + routeId + " :: " + route.emailSuccess);
    if (routeId === 'test') {
        console.log("minto test");
        return ( 
            <Test navigator={navigator} emailSuccess={route.emailSuccess} />
        );
    } else if (routeId === 'Invitation') {
        console.log("into Invitation");
        return ( 
            <Invitation navigator={navigator} customerId={route.customerId} />
        );
    } else {
        console.log("into demo");
        return (
            <OnBoardingDemo navigator={navigator} />
        );
    }
}
```

and to navigate to a different scene I did :

```
    _navigator.push({
        id: 'test',
    });
```

The sequence is Demo > Invitation > Test

For example everytime I am on the `Test` scene, when I rotate the device it goes back to the `Demo` scene. How to make it stay on the `Test` scene?

Comment: I am also having this issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: Is this resolved ?